# How can I access the checked property of a checkbox which is indexed by an *ngFor loop - Angular

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, data-binding

I have a list of drop-down elements, which is indexed by an *ngFor loop.

```
<div class="item-wrapper" *ngIf="showItems">
  <div class="wrap-collapsible" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <input id="{{i}}" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <label for="{{i}}" class="dropdown-toggle" tabindex="0" (click)="selectItem(item)">
      Threat {{item.id}}: {{item.category}}
    </label>
    <div class="collapsible-content">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <p class="title">{{item.title}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Per default, the checkbox input is selected on click, and stays checked when selecting other elements.

How would I go about unchecking all elements except the last one clicked?

I've tried doing...

`<input id="{{i}}" type="checkbox" [checked]="i == selectedElement">`

...while passing the index in the selectItem() method, where selectedElement is set to i. This doesn't work, because then no item is selectable.

Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the change function of your input :

```
<input id="{{i}}" class="toggle" type="checkbox" (change)="setLastClicked(item)">
```

In your TS :

```
setLastClicked(item) {
  this.lastSelected = item;
}
```

You can now use that memory reference to compare to the items when you [un]check them all :

```
toggleCheck() {
  this.items.forEach(item => item.checked = {
    if(item === this.lastSelected) return;
    item.checked = !item.checked;
  });
}
```

With a memory reference, you don't need the ID anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot, calling setLastClicked(item) in the (change) is what did the trick. Then I just set  [checked]="i == lastSelected".